# How do I design this algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

In an imaginary land the people have an ability to teleport through each other if they are facing each other. I am supposed to write an algorithm to find how many teleportations will be made based on the input. If there is a 1 that means the person is facing right and if there is a 2 that means the person is facing left.

The first line is a number N, the number of people in the land.
In the second line there are N numbers, either 1 or 2.

```
Input         Output
3             2
1 2 2

Input         Output
4             0
2 2 1 1
```

This is my code, but when a person faced right comes across a person facing left, they teleport through each other but the algorithm isn't checking if there are more people facing right behind the first person.

```
int main()
{
    int n, a, teleportiranja = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int niza[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        niza[i] = a;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        if (niza[x] == 1 && niza[x + 1] == 2)
        {
            swap(niza[x], niza[x + 1]);
            teleportiranja++;
        }
     }

   cout << teleportiranja << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand case 1. Besides, you may try using a stack. You may also emulate a stack with a simple array.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how the output is `2` and `0`. Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: I think the original definition of 1s and 2s is a typo. `1` represents a person facing right while `2`, left. That's the only way I can reason the test cases. For the first one, we are given `1 2 2`, which is equivalent to `-> <- <-`. Clearly, two teleports happen, as expected; the left guy passes through two right guys (or you can think of it in reverse). In the second example, we're given `2 2 1 1`, which becomes `<- <- -> ->`. As we can see, no one is facing eaching other and so no teleports happen.

Comment: I am really sorry for the typo but you got it besides that.

Comment: Did you try *trying* first before going to an Internet community for help?

Comment: I'm a 14 year old teenager trying to learn competitive programming and believe me I've known this task/exercise for month and a half and the closest I could get was this, but now thanks to the first answer and his idea I fixed it myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do check the people right behind the first person but after you checked everyone once, you stop. You need a second loop that keeps checking for teleports until no further teleports are found. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a, teleportiranja = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int niza[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        niza[i] = a;
    }

    bool required_teleports;
    do {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            required_teleports = false;
            if (niza[x] == 1 && niza[x + 1] == 2) {
                swap(niza[x], niza[x + 1]);
                teleportiranja++;
                required_teleports = true;
            }
        }
    } while (required_teleports);
    cout << teleportiranja << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work and I don't understand why, but your idea really helped me and I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Dont know the timeconstraint for the problem but this solution is O(N^2) but O(N) is possible.

Comment: @ZimbakovTech I tested it with the examples you provided and it gave the correct results. It would probably help others to be more specific about what went wrong for you and how you fixed it. But I'm glad it worked out in the end for you!

Comment: @Bjorne I had an inkling that there was a clever closed-form solution here but if Zimbakov used it, it would probably be even more obvious that he didn't do his homework himself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Every person facing left (value 2) will have to pass all people facing right (value 1) that comes before him. So if we pick any person with value 2 he will teleport an amount equal to the number of that come before him with value 1. This can be done with a single loop in O(n) time by keeping track of the number of 1s so far and when we reach a 2 we add the current number of 1s to the total amount of teleportations.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int ones = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 1)
            ones++;
        else cnt += ones;
    }
   cout << cnt << endl;

   return 0;
}
```